# How to display SVG in Firefox using <object>?

Tags: html, firefox, svg

I'm trying to display SVG, using <object>, in Firefox.

If I load the index.xhtml locally, rather than through a HTTP server, the page loads correctly.

However, if I load through a HTTP server, Firefox displays nothing, but rather informs me a plugin is required.

I've spent about two hours looking for and trying different solutions, to no avail.  I'm now extraordinarily annoyed and frustrated.

This is the page;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <head>
    <title>Daily Agera Stats</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table cellpadding="4" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
      <tr>
        <td><object data="clicks_with_data_per_day_all_sources.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></td>
        <td><object data="clicks_with_data_per_day_criteo_only.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></td>
        <td><object data="impressions_per_day_with_data.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></td>
        <td><object data="impressions_per_day_with_data_from_clickers.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><object data="referrer_urls.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></td>
        <td><object data="conversions_per_day_with_data.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></td>
        <td><object data="conversions_per_day_with_data_from_clickers.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that the WWW server (lighttpd) has been configured to serve .xhtml as "application/xhtml+xml".

Given the page works off-line, I'm guessing this is a MIME issue of some kind.  The total absence of meaningful documentation or error messages or anything one might consider an intuitive solution is INCREDIBLY ANNOYING.

The SVG is generated by GnuPlot and is quite long.  The head looks like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"  standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg 
 width="320" height="256" 
 viewBox="0 0 320 256"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>

<title>Gnuplot</title>
<desc>Produced by GNUPLOT 4.6 patchlevel 0 </desc>
```

Any help deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer.

DESPITE the MIME type being specified in the <object> tag, you must ALSO configure the HTTP server to serve that MIME type for .svg.

I had of course seen this almost at the start, but I assumed - HA! - that since I was actually specifying the type, the browser would know what to do.

What the hell is the point of the type attribute if the browser ignores it?

Comment: The point of the `type` attribute is to allow the browser to skip requesting a resource if it knows it can't handle the type — it's a hint, not the authoritative statement. [“If the value of this attribute differs from the HTTP Content-Type returned by the server when the object is retrieved, the HTTP Content-Type takes precedence.”](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#adef-type-OBJECT). The server should **always** be configured to return correct `Content-Type`s for **all** resources.

Comment: Also, if the browser would try and interpret random content types from the server using the one specified in the markup it would open up lots of possibilities for sending carefully crafted files to trigger security bugs in code designed for other file types.

Comment: @Kevin: hmm; and now I think about it, the server indeed is returning a type - it is configured to return a default type if nothing else matches.

Comment: @robertc That's not an “if” — browsers *do* guess at things being HTML (in reaction to misconfigured servers), and there *are* security hazards that arise due to those browsers existing.